# Edit Mode Delete Spinner Icon for Specific TableView Rows

Tags: iphone, uitableview, editmode

I have a grouped tableview.  Each section has three rows.  I need to be able to delete one section at a time.  Using the standard edit mode, I can make it work.  However, the delete icon shows up to the left of each cell, not just the first row in each section.

Is there a way to suppress the little spinner icon for all rows except the first?

I am hoping there is an easy way to do this without subclassing.

Here is a screenshot to help visualize it: http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/ll-EJY5ACw7oqHH1xKBQ8w?feat=directlink

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting rows, make a parent `UIView` that contains a `UILabel` and custom `UIButton` as subviews. Set this parent view as the [section header view](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:).

The button should be wired up to trigger a method that deletes rows by, for example, flipping a `BOOL` state flag for that section and then reloading the table:

```
- (void) deleteMySection:(id)sender {
    self.showMySection = NO;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Your [`-numberOfSectionsInTableView:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW9) delegate method will accordingly adjust its output depending on the state of this boolean flag, e.g.

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tv {
    return ((showMySection) ? numberOfSections : numberOfSections - 1);
}
```